# Android Intent filter not working for all devices (action SEND and SEND_MULTIPLE)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an android containing an activity that can receive pictures sent to it by the android share menu. The activity has this configuration in the manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am using the mimeType filter to allow only images to be sent to the activity.

Apparently, this is not working on all devices. I have tested it on the Nexus S and Galaxy S/S2 and it worked great, but I've got complaints from some users (especially xperia) saying the app it not showing in the Share menu when it's opened on a photo from the gallery.

The app is using SDK 2.1 sdk 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule that says that an activity have a "share" menu that supports any particular `Intent` filter.

That being said, I would add:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to your filter.

Comment: What does adding a category to the intent-filter mean? Cannot find a decent explanation on the android help... Did not get what you meant in the first line.

Comment: @Idan: It means you are matching on an `Intent` that contains a category. My apologies for that opening sentence, it is fixed now.

Comment: My activity is the receiver.. The share menu is opened using other apps (like the gallery) and my app should be one of the options inside that share menu. It still does not explain why it is working on some devices and not working on others.

Comment: @Idan: You are welcome to go around and force all device manufacturers, at gunpoint, to implement a "share" menu that will match your activity. Note that this will likely violate several laws. Short of that, there is no rule that says that an activity from a device manufacturer has to have a "share" menu that meets your criteria. If you are not including the `DEFAULT` category in your `<intent-filter>`, I suggest you try it, as that is what Google does with its own apps.